# xml parsing with repeated names of nodes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Please tell me the best way to parse the below xml in java. Here I have the same name for root(element) and other nodes.Is that possible to use jaxb or I have to stick in to normal dom?

```
<element exp="office_adr" display="false" id="o_a2">
    <element exp="office1" display="false" id="o2">
            <element exp="city1" display="false" id="c1">
                <element exp="address1" display="true" id="h_1">
                    <element exp="ad1" display="false" id="h_2"/>
                    <element exp="ad2" display="false" id="h_3"/>
                    <element exp="ad3" display="false" id="h_4"/>
                    <element exp="ad4" display="false" id="h_5"/>
                    <element exp="ad5" display="false" id="h_6"/>
                </element>
                <element exp="address2" display="true" id="h_8">
                    <element exp="ad7" display="false" id="h_9"/>
                    <element exp="ad8" display="false" id="h_10"/>
                </element>
                <element exp="address3" display="true" id="h_11">
                    <element exp="ad9" display="false" id="h_12"/>
                </element>
            </element>
    </element>
    <element exp="office2" display="false" id="o2">
            <element exp="city2" display="false" id="c2">
                <element exp="address3" display="true" id="a_1">
                    <element exp="ad1" display="false" id="a_2"/>
                    <element exp="ad2" display="false" id="a_3"/>
                    <element exp="ad3" display="false" id="a_4"/>
                    <element exp="ad4" display="false" id="a_5"/>
                    <element exp="ad5" display="false" id="a_6"/>
                </element>
                <element exp="address2" display="true" id="a_8">
                    <element exp="ad7" display="false" id="a_9"/>
                    <element exp="ad8" display="false" id="a_10"/>
                </element>
                <element exp="address3" display="true" id="a_11">
                    <element exp="ad9" display="false" id="a_12"/>
                </element>
            </element>
    </element>
</element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem with JAXB:

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXB;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public class Element
{
    private String exp;
    private boolean display;
    private String id;
    private Collection<Element> element;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getExp()
    {
        return exp;
    }
    public void setExp(String exp)
    {
        this.exp = exp;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public boolean isDisplay()
    {
        return display;
    }
    public void setDisplay(boolean display)
    {
        this.display = display;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Collection<Element> getElement()
    {
        return element;
    }
    public void setElement(Collection<Element> element)
    {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Element e = JAXB.unmarshal(new File("C:/testFile.xml"), Element.class);
        System.out.println(e.getElement().size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And no problem for SAX, or DOM, or any other XML handling code. That's a particularly ugly way to write XML, but it's entirely legitimate.